# При появлении и сокрытии клавиатуры анимация поля ввода ведет себя странно ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, анимация

Задача: при появлении клавиатуры сдвигать поле ввода вверх, при сокрытии, сдвигать вниз (анимировано).

Делаю простую анимацию, но почему то поле анимируется как клавиатура.
Важно, что это проявляется, только если запускать анимацию по событию `keyboardWillShow:`, `keyboardWillHide:`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, `textFieldDidEndEditing:` (и с ними схожими). Если ту же анимацию запускать просто по нажатию произвольной кнопки, то все в порядке.

[Ссылка на видео происходящего](https://yadi.sk/i/ZUdhvWSInwjct/)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pinCodeTextField;
- (void) hideKeyboard;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - keyboard movements

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
//    [self performSelector:@selector(animateShiftViews:) withObject:@(-160) afterDelay:0.1];
    [self animateShiftViews:@(-160)];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self animateShiftViews:@(160)];
}

- (void) animateShiftViews:(NSNumber*) shift
{
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.pinCodeTextField.center.x, self.pinCodeTextField.center.y);
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.pinCodeTextField.frame.origin.x, self.pinCodeTextField.frame.origin.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^
     {
         self.pinCodeTextField.frame = CGRectOffset(self.pinCodeTextField.frame, 0, [shift floatValue]);
     }];
}

-(void)hideKeyboard
{
    [self.pinCodeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)upButtonDidPress:(id)sender
{
    [self animateShiftViews:@(-160)];
}

- (IBAction)downButtonDidPress:(id)sender
{
    [self animateShiftViews:@(160)];
}


@end
```

Comment: вроде никакой ошибки нет. это весь код? может там еще что то участвовать?

Comment: Нет, это весь код. Что значит нет никакой ошибки? Вы видео видели(или запускали)? Анимация ведет себя абсолютно по другому, когда появляется/исчезает клавиатура.

Comment: Гы гы, с одной стороны это баг, а с другой стороны и не баг, попробуйте как самое простое решение двигать UITextView вниз, делайте перерасчет координат его местоположения.

Comment: Обратитесь еще и к [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), возможно ответ лежит на поверхности.

Comment: А ваш  `textField` случайно не на  `UIScrollView` находится?

Comment: Нет, просто на вьюшке